# android ant -pre-compile vs -pre-build

Tags: android, ant, build

I'm working on an android project where we build our releases with ant. We use the Android-ant target `-pre-compile` when changing the `versionName` and some other flags in the code. There is also a `-pre-build` android-ant target you can use.

Does anyone know the difference between those two targets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the build.xml in the SDK's ant tools folder we have:

```
<target name="-compile" depends="-build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile">
```

Both -pre-compile and -pre-build are empty targets by default and therefore do nothing. The only difference is that -pre-build will run before -code-gen (which is not empty), whilst -pre-compile runs after it.

Comment: Ok, I see. So if you do something with the compiled resources you would have to use the -pre-compile else it just doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Pre compile is often used for preprocessing purposes but no one would really want to live with those J2ME techs anymore.

Prebuild could be the place for checking your resources for instance.

Comment: So, if one wonted to do a j2me preprocessing port -pre-compile is where to put it.

Comment: Yes. But, for sure, it's not a long term choice. You will pay a heavy price for choosing such a non standard, non OO technology...*